# Remove Cookies but keep only automatic login info on some sites

Tags: cookies, browsing

I do not like the idea of being targeted through my cookies but I would like to still be able not to type my login info everytime I crawl the web (gmail, facebook, etc.)

Is there a way to remove all other data but keep only this functionality on a per-site basis ? From the info I could get, cookies seem function on an all or nothing basis, I was wondering if I could keep some of the comfort it brings without giving out all my info and getting spied on.

For the record, I am using chrome (not the best for privacy, I know, but ut's faster)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 59 and in `chrome://settings/content/cookies` it allows to add specific sites where cookies are blocked, cleared on exit, or allowed (if the default is to block). I think other browsers have the same options somewhere..